# Add values for each cell values those are followed up and add 0 for missing date values in excel

Tags: excel, ms-office

I have two columns

```
Quantity      Date
2            02/01/2014
3            04/01/2014
4            07/01/2014
5            07/01/2014
1            08/01/2014
3            08/01/2014
```

I want to add the quantity values for each date and put 0 for dates those are missing. So end result would look like below

```
Quantity      Date
0            01/01/2014
2            02/01/2014
0            03/01/2014
3            04/01/2014
0            05/01/2014
0            06/01/2014
9            07/01/2014
4            08/01/2014
0            09/01/2014
.            ...
.            ...
.            ...
```

Can't think of a way, can someone help please

Answer (score 0):

I don't have Excel in front of me, but I'll take a stab at it.

Leave your first dataset in `Sheet1`, but reverse the columns.

Then type

```
Date
01/01/2014
02/01/2014
03/01/2014
....
```

...into Column `A` of `Sheet2` and drag the cells down to expand the series as far as it needs to go.

Then do a `=vlookup(A1, Sheet1!A$1$:B$99999$, 2, FALSE)` in column `B` of sheet two.

You'll get errors, where you don't have dates in `Sheet1`, so you can fill those in by modifying the above equation to: `=IFERROR(vlookup(A1, Sheet1!A$1$:B$99999$, 2, FALSE), 0)`

(I think).